# How can I make the cin.getline work?

Tags: c++

```
void CDepartment::Engg() {         
 system("cls");
 Invent.welcome();
 cout<<"\t     (ADD AN ASSET)\n=========================================================\n\t COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING\n=========================================================\n";

 cout<<"\tWhich department?\n\t-Civil Engineering\n\t-ECE and CPE\n\t-[Ba]ck\n\n\tChoice:";
 cin.getline(choice_1,20);  

 if (strcmp(choice_1,back)==0){
                     Invent.add();}
 Invent.Info();    
}
```

`choice_1` is declared globally. It does not work. It skips the `cin.getline(choice_1,20);`. How can I make it to work?

Comment: How do you know its skipping `cin.getline(choice_1,20);`. Does it work if you make choice_1 a local variable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [`cin.ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/) just before `cin.getline()`? Sometimes it might help it clears (may not exactly clears, it "*extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them*") unwanted characters stored in buffer.

```
//...
cout<<"\tWhich department?\n\t-Civil Engineering\n\t-ECE and CPE\n\t-[Ba]ck\n\n\tChoice:";
cin.ignore(256, '\n');
cin.getline(choice_1,20);  
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a step-by-step debug?
See what happens to the choice_1 variable?

**Edit**: Try adding a `cin.get();` before your line, otherwise it might just be attempting to read a blank "\n" instead of the actual input.